# How to remove tick listener in Flash CC Canvas Project

Tags: javascript, flash, canvas

i am trying to rotate a MovieCip on mouseover and make it stop at mouseout in a Flash CC Canvas project; i have tried many many things, none seems to work for me.... 
initially i was trying to use setInterval with no succes, somehow i manage to rotate it continuosly with "thick" event listener, but i can not make it stop on mouseout, i am trying to removeEventListener ("tick") to stop repeating the rotation code.... what i am doing wrong?
By the way, i am a graphic designer trying to learn how to code, please excuse my lack of basic understanding on code logic....and my english. thanks in advance!!

```
var frequency = 1;
stage.enableMouseOver(frequency);

this.adelante.on("mouseover", rotaDerecha.bind(this));

function rotaDerecha() {    
    this.on("tick", Timer.bind(this));
    function Timer() {
        this.rueda.rotation += 2;
}
    this.adelante.off("mouseout", stoper.bind(this));
    function stoper(){
        this.off("tick", Timer.bind(this));
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a reference to the function you wanna remove. Bind creates a new function, also I think you call `off` where you want to call `on`, you can do something like this:

```
var frequency = 1;
stage.enableMouseOver(frequency);

this.adelante.on("mouseover", rotaDerecha.bind(this));

function rotaDerecha() {
    var timer = (function() {
        this.rueda.rotation += 2;
    }).bind(this)
    this.on("tick", timer);
    this.adelante.on("mouseout", function () {
        this.off("tick", timer);
    }.bind(this));
}
```

Or maybe without bind, it makes it a bit better readable:

```
function rotaDerecha() {
    var self = this
    var timer = function() {
        self.rueda.rotation += 2;
    }
    self.on("tick", timer);
    self.adelante.on("mouseout", function () {
        self.off("tick", timer);
    });
}
```